# password hashing - success probability of cracking

Tags: security, hash, passwords, password-encryption

We have the following hash function that maps a 4 digit password.

> h(abcd) = (d+c^2+b^3+a^4) mod 100, where a,b,c,d = {0...9}.

What is the success probability of someone finding the password if the server stored the unhashed vs hashed versions of the password?

I know that we have a total of 10^4 possible 4-digit unhashed psswords. So if an exhaustive search is run on a NOT-hashed list, then the success probability will be 1/10^4 = 1/10000.

But how do I know what the probability is for the hashed storing of the passwords? Many passwords will hash to the same value. I don't see an emerging pattern.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about calculating a probability and not about programming.

Comment: For so weak passwords you can just calculate all possible combinations and count the unique "hashes", that should take about some milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

First, read [Thomas Pornin's canonical answer to "How to securely hash passwords?"](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846/39623)

Second, quit using your custom hash function and start using PBKDF2, bcrypt, or scrypt with a sufficiently large number of iterations/work factor.

Note that for 4 digit PINs, no possible work factor is high enough, since an offline attacker is likely to have orders of magnitude more computing power, and thus if you want users to wait less than an hour, any attacker's going to crunch through your complete list in very little time, and find 100% of the passwords.

So, third, quit using 4 digit passwords, and start using long, complex passwords - or even longer numeric only passwords.

ETA: For an offline attack, 100% - they'll find every single password in no time at all by the time scales normally used.

Comment: I understand all of this above information. I am not new to this. The reason I gave such a simple hash function is not because I will use it anywhere. It is dumb to, when there exists phPass and other good libraries. My questioin is purely theoretical.